# SQL Server Dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am executing Dynamic SQL,

```
sqlQuery = " SELECT ";
sqlQuery += _Allowed + " , "; 
sqlQuery += " + cast( ";
sqlQuery += " _ID as nvarchar ) ";
sqlQuery += " FROM ";
sqlQuery += " TBL_SUCCESS ";
```

when i execute it suppose to return common separated values like 2,4,5 in single column

instead it return values in separate column

my MyDataTable suppose to populate

```
Column1
2,4,5
```

but it populates

```
column1  column2  column3
2         4         5
```

How to get the output?

Comment: there is nothing magic about the sql string, distinct from other strings. if you print it out, just as you would print out any other string, you'll see the exact final string that will get sent to the database. from there, you can probably figure out what you want to modify, to get it to look the way you want, and once you know that, you can probably figure out how to achieve that in your dynamic sql string as well.

Answer (score 1):

Need to see the value of `_Allowed` to know what else is happening, but you need to at least put quotes around the comma and concatenate it inside the SQL statement, like this:

```
sqlQuery += _Allowed + " + ' , ' ";
```